# Silverlight app accessing files across web apps -- clientaccesspolicy.xml asks for login

Tags: silverlight, sharepoint, iis, sharepoint-2010

In SharePoint 2010, I have a Silverlight app running on WebApp1 which accesses a file on WebApp2.

Every time this happens, I see a login window pop up to give credentials to access WebApp2. In fiddler, I'm able to see that this comes after a `401` response to an attempt to access `ClientAccessPolicy.xml` on WebApp2

After entering credentials, I no longer see the login window, but as soon as my session expires, I'm prompted for it again.

I'm logged into the box as an administrator and I am a domain administrator on both WebApp1 and WebApp2.

I've checked folder AND item permissions on `ClientAccessPolicy.xml` and 'Everyone' has Read permissions at least. I've tried giving myself explicit full-control permissions as well.

**How can I get it to stop prompting me?**

I've played with a ton of IIS security settings (IIS-wide authentication, site-level authentication, IIS Manager Permissions...) in addition to adding both fully-qualified URLs for WebApp1 and WebApp2 to "Trusted Site" in IE9, where I've set `User Authentication` to `Automatic logon with current user name and password`

Comment: can you edit your post and show how you access the file on WebApp2?